# Why is $gN = N$ for $g \in N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Suppose we have a homomorphism defined as $\phi: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z_3}$, where $\mathbb{Z_3}$ is a group under addition. Then $\ker{\phi}$ will be the set $3\mathbb{Z}=\{0, 3, 6, ..., 27, ...\}$. Now let's take some element in the kernel of $\phi$ (say, $3$) and take the product with the kernel of $\phi$. We will then have $3+\ker{\phi} = \{3, 6, 9, ...,\}$. Basically, this operation appears to eliminate all elements of the kernel, which precede $3$.

I'm wondering what I'm not seeing here, to be able to be satisfied that all cosets of the kernel of some homomorphism must be the kernel of the homomoprhism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $3\mathbb{Z}=\{...,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,...\}$, so $3+\ker(\phi)=\{...,-6,-3,0,3,6,...\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$3\mathbb Z=\{\dots, -9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,\dots\}$. The integers wouldn't be a group under addition if they didn't have negative numbers.